# Why is this Variable Losing its Value?

Tags: python

Basically, my sample dataset looks like the following:

```
Machine Type: PC,
IP Address: 10.0.0.1,
Location: Denver,USA
Machine Type: Thin Client,
IP Address: 10.0.0.2,
Location: Seattle, USA
```

I am trying to group every 3 lines together. So each 3 lines of the data set are related (I.e the PC's IP is 10.0.0.1 and is in Denver, the next device is a thin client in Seattle and so on)

My goal is to have Python put each of these 3 values into their own variables, so that later on in the script (omitted from my code below for brevity), I can pass them to a CSV.

My problem is that one of the variables is losing its value in the `if i == 3:` block.

Take a look at the following code to see an example of the issue:

```
output = """
Machine Type: PC,
IP Address: 10.0.0.1,
Location: Denver,USA
Machine Type: Thin Client,
IP Address: 10.0.0.2,
Location: Seattle, USA

 """

i = 0
output = output.split("\n")

for line in output:
    if "PC" in line:
        machine = line[-3:-1]

    if "Thin Client" in line:
        machine = line[-11:-1]

    if "IP Address" in line:
        address = line[-8:-1]

    if "Location" in line:        
        location = line[-12:-1]
        print(location)

    i = i + 1
    if i == 3:
        print(machine, address, location)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytest.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(machine, address, location) 
NameError: name 'location' is not defined
```

Python is telling me that the `location` variable isn't defined, but I don't see how that's true because it was defined on the third iteration of the for loop before it was passed off to the print statement.

I can actually prove it's being defined with the following code:

```
output = """
Machine Type: PC,
IP Address: 10.0.0.1,
Location: Denver,USA
Machine Type: Thin Client,
IP Address: 10.0.0.2,
Location: Seattle, USA

 """

output = output.split("\n")

for line in output:
    if "PC" in line:
        machine = line[-3:-1]

    if "Thin Client" in line:
        machine = line[-11:-1]

    if "IP Address" in line:
        address = line[-8:-1]

    if "Location" in line:
        location = line[-12:-1]
        print(location)
```

Output:

```
Denver,US
Seattle, US
```

I am really lost here. Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this? Or have any suggestions on how to do this in a better way?

Comment: The PROBLEM here is that your test case has a blank line at the beginning (where you say `output = """`), so by the time `i` gets to 3, you have not seen a location yet.  I'll post a much smarter way to do this.

Comment: Beside the point, but are you aware that Python 2 is EOL? You should switch to Python 3 right away, unless you're stuck with legacy stuff.

Comment: To be extra clear, the variable isn't "losing its value", it's just not being defined in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Counting lines is the wrong answer.  If you want an output after "Location", then do the output when you get "Location".  Also, remember that when you say

```
output = """
xxx
"""
```

That has a newline at the beginning, and an extra newline at the end.  To eliminate those, you need to use a backslash:

```
output = """\
xxx"""
```

It's better to be able to ignore blank lines, like this does.

```
output = """
Machine Type: PC,
IP Address: 10.0.0.1,
Location: Denver,USA
Machine Type: Thin Client,
IP Address: 10.0.0.2,
Location: Seattle, USA
"""
for line in output.splitlines():
    parts = line.split(': ')
    if parts[0] == 'Machine Type':
        machine = parts[1]
    elif parts[0] == "IP Address":
        address = parts[1]
    elif parts[0] == "Location":
        location = parts[1]
        print(machine, address, location)
```

Output:

```
PC, 10.0.0.1, Denver,USA
Thin Client, 10.0.0.2, Seattle, USA
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written is very vulnerable to breakage if the formatting isn't exactly as expected -- a blank line, stray whitespace, etc can easily throw it off.  Since you're using the line number (`i`) to decide whether or not `location` has been defined, a blank line will mess you up, as will reordering the data, adding another line, etc.

Here's an approach that aims to just turn your format (as far as I can infer it) into a generic list of dictionaries rather than assigning individual pieces of data to named variables:

```
output = """
Machine Type: PC,
IP Address: 10.0.0.1,
Location: Denver,USA
Machine Type: Thin Client,
IP Address: 10.0.0.2,
Location: Seattle, USA

 """

data = [{}]
for line in output.split("\n"):
    if not ":" in line:
        continue
    line = line.strip().rstrip(",")
    k, v = line.split(":")
    k = max(k.lower().strip().split(), key=len)
    if k in data[-1]:
        data.append({})
    data[-1][k] = v.strip()
```

This code isn't aware of any of the particular variables, or know (or care) what order they're in, but it produces your original three variables as entries in a dictionary that you can access any way you like:

```
print(data)
# [{'machine': 'PC', 'address': '10.0.0.1', 'location': 'Denver,USA'}, {'machine': 'Thin Client', 'address': '10.0.0.2', 'location': 'Seattle, USA'}]

for d in data:
    print(list(d.values()))
# ['PC', '10.0.0.1', 'Denver,USA']
# ['Thin Client', '10.0.0.2', 'Seattle, USA']

print([d["machine"] for d in data])
# ['PC', 'Thin Client']
```

Comment: Why do you do `max(k.lower().strip().split(), key=len)`? That drops the important bits "type" and "IP", and it doesn't seem necessary in any case.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

output = """
Machine Type: PC,
IP Address: 10.0.0.1,
Location: Denver,USA
Machine Type: Thin Client,
IP Address: 10.0.0.2,
Location: Seattle, USA
"""

ids = ['Machine Type', 'IP Address', 'Location']
values = []
for id in ids:
    values.append([x.split(': ')[1] for x in re.findall(f"({id}:.*)\n", output)])

for value in zip(*values):
    print(*value)
```

Output:

```
PC, 10.0.0.1, Denver,USA
Thin Client, 10.0.0.2, Seattle, USA
```